# IONIC cant centered place holder in IOS

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, placeholder

Place holder property "text-align:center"is not working in IOS, the text locate at top, but in "ionic serve -l " and in all browser`s it works, but not in device. The css is like this:

```
.input-login{
  color: white !important;
  font-family: 'Din Condensed';
  font-size: 22px !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Image:
[image: place holder problem in ionic]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was to set properties straight in the class "placeholder" and not in the tag, and solve the ios build problem.

This was the solution:

```
/** Place Holder */

.placeholder{
  vertical-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  vertical-align: center;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  vertical-align: center;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  vertical-align: center;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  vertical-align: center;
}

/** End Place holder */
```